# How do I keep an input:checkbox and an a tag on same line?

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

I've got markup like this:

```
<div class="radio-choice score bottom">
  <input type="radio" name="name" value="v1" class="myradio" 
      /><a target="_blank" href="https://example.com/gudlink">Long description of a very interesting article</a>
</div>
```

I'm using a multi-column bootstrap grid. I want the above html to be rendered like so:

```
[] Long description of a ve
```

Instead, I get this:

```
[]
Long description of a very interesting article
```

That line stays on a single line, but it extends past the column boundaries.

Two questions:

1. How do I keep the text on the same line as the checkbox regardless of its length?
2. How do I truncate the text (see markup below -- I am using `white-space: nowrap;` and `overflow-x: hidden;`)?

### The CSS:

I am using the following SCSS:

```
div.radio-choice.score {
    a {
        overflow-x: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    &:hover {
        overflow-x: visible;
    }
    input[type="radio"].myradio {
        width:  auto;
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

When I was using a series of `span` tags in a `p` tag I got the behavior I wanted. If I put the `input` and `a` tags in a span I get the same behavior -- the `a` tag starts on the next line, and its text spills out to the right.

This might be instructive: when I use the DOM inspector I see that for the rules for `div.radio-choice.score a` the `overflow-x: hidden;` line is struck through, but the `white-space: nowrap;` line isn't.  Given that there are other S/O articles talking about truncating anchor text, why would this rule be struck through?

For the line-breaking problem my current solution is to style the checkbox with `margin-left: -2em;` but I expect there's a better way to do that.

As for why my anchor text isn't being truncated, I'll have to narrow it down. Right now I'm working with 500 lines of SCSS and there could easily be something else interfering with it. But in the meantime I'm hoping someone who ran into this and found the solution, or has a great internal grasp of the mechanics of CSS, could weigh in.

Comment: what about using display table for the parent and display table-cell for the children?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```css
a {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
a:hover {
  overflow-x: visible;
}
input[type="radio"].myradio {
  width:  auto;
  display: inline;
}
    
/*
  [ Solution ]
*/
.radio-choice {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  border: 4px grey solid;
  padding: 4px;
}

a {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-choice score bottom">
  <input type="radio" name="name" value="v1" class="myradio" />
  <a target="_blank" href="https://example.com/gudlink">Long description of a very interesting article</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the `input` and `a` tags are given `display: inline-block` to keep them on the same line.

I added ellipsis for the text overflow of the hyperlink.

```css
div.radio-choice.score {
  max-width: 150px; /* Assumption to create the effect */
}

a {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100px; /* Assumption to create the effect */
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  overflow-x: visible;
}

input[type="radio"].myradio {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-choice score bottom">
  <input type="radio" name="name" value="v1" class="myradio" /><!--
  --><a target="_blank" href="https://example.com/gudlink">Long description of a very interesting article</a>
</div>
```